# How to return a class to a onPostExecute?

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-maps

Update, please see below.

How do I return my class LocationData and my ArrayList listOfObjects to the onPostExecute()? I want to use it in my UI and right now it is in the background in an AsyncTask. Also I want to add markers with:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
    .title(name));
```

so that I can add each new location to the map after each loop.

Do I place the above in the onPostExecute after returning the LocationData class?

```
    try {

        String apples = endpoint.listContactInfo().execute().toString();

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(apples);

        JSONArray jsonArr = jObject.getJSONArray("items");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ID);
            String nameFirst1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
            String nameLast1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
            String emailAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String streetAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            String phone1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_PHONE);

            // test to see if made it to string
            Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "First Name: " + nameFirst1 + " Last Name: "
                    + nameLast1);

            address = coder.getFromLocationName(streetAddress1, 5);

            Address location1 = address.get(0);

            // SET LAT LNG VALUES FOR MARKER POINT

            lati = location1.getLatitude();
            longi = location1.getLongitude();

            Log.d("Location", "Location:" + lati + " " + longi);

            class LocationData {
                private double lat;
                private double longitude;
                private String name;

                public LocationData(double lat, double longitude,
                        String name) {
                    this.lat = lat;
                    this.longitude = longitude;
                    this.name = name;
                }

                public void setLat(double lat) {
                    this.lat = lat;
                }

                public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
                    this.longitude = longitude;
                }

                public double getLat() {
                    return lat;
                }

                public double getLongitude() {
                    return longitude;
                }

                public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
                }

                public String getName() {
                    return name;
                }

            }

            ArrayList<LocationData> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

            listOfObjects.add(new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1));

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (long) 0;

}

// WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO RETURN LocationData Class here
// ADD MARKER TO MAP UI
protected void onPostExecute() {

    // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    // .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
    // .title("Hello world"));
```

This may seem elementary but I've created this method:
     public ArrayList getLocationData() {

```
                                 ArrayList<LocationData> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

                                 listOfObjects.add(new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1));

                                 return listOfObjects;
                             }
```

within my LocationData class. I then placed LocationData.getLocationData(); with the onPostExecute and I get the LocationData can't be resolved. The code together looks like this at the moment:

```
 try {

    String apples = endpoint.listContactInfo().execute().toString();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(apples);

    JSONArray jsonArr = jObject.getJSONArray("items");

     for(int i =0 ; i<jsonArr.length() ;i++ ){
         JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ID);
                    final String nameFirst1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String nameLast1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String emailAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String streetAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String phone1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_PHONE);

                    //test to see if made it to string
                    Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "First Name: " + nameFirst1 + " Last Name: " + nameLast1);

                       address = coder.getFromLocationName(streetAddress1,5);

                        Address location1 = address.get(0);

                        // SET LAT LNG VALUES FOR MARKER POINT

                     lati = location1.getLatitude();
                         longi = location1.getLongitude();

                         Log.d("Location", "Location:" + lati + " " +  longi);


                       class LocationData {
                             private double lat;
                             private double longitude;
                             private String name;

                             public LocationData(double lat, double longitude, String name) {
                                 this.lat = lat;
                                 this.longitude = longitude;
                                 this.name = name;
                             }

                             public void setLat(double lat) {
                                 this.lat = lat;
                             }

                             public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
                                 this.longitude = longitude;
                             }

                             public double getLat() {
                                 return lat;
                             }

                             public double getLongitude() {
                                 return longitude;
                             }

                             public void setName(String name) {
                                   this.name = name;
                                }

                             public String getName() {
                                 return name;



                                }

                             public ArrayList<LocationData> getLocationData() {

                                 ArrayList<LocationData> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

                                 listOfObjects.add(new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1));

                                 return listOfObjects;
                             }

                             }

     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
      return (long) 0;


    }
    //WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO RETURN LocationData Class here
         // ADD MARKER TO MAP UI
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result ) {

                  //CANT BE RESOLVED
        LocationData.getLocationData();

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        //.position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
        // .title("Hello world"));
```

Here are my changes based upon @Sustain recommendations. I seem to not be getting any map markers now. Anyone see anything?

```
public class FinderActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener  {


GoogleMap mMap;
Location myLocation;
EditText length;
String lengthString;
LocationManager locationmanager;
double lati;
double longi;
String nameFirst1;
//Spinner s;

   List<Address> address;
   Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "nameFirst";
private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "nameLast";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "emailAddress";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "streetAddress";
private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";

private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
JSONArray contacts = null;


private static class LocationData {
     private double lat;
     private double longitude;
     private String name;

     public LocationData(double lat, double longitude, String name) {
         this.lat = lat;
         this.longitude = longitude;
         this.name = name;
     }

     public void setLat(double lat) {
         this.lat = lat;
     }

     public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
         this.longitude = longitude;
     }

     public double getLat() {
         return lat;
     }

     public double getLongitude() {
         return longitude;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
        }

     public String getName() {
         return name;

        }

     }

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (mMap!= null) {

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(17));

        }

    LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria cr = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);

    Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20, 0, (LocationListener) this);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng((new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))));


    new EndpointsTask().execute(getApplicationContext());

}

public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, LocationData, Long> {

    private List<LocationData> locationList = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

    public Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Contactinfoendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Contactinfoendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Contactinfoendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();

  try {

    String apples = endpoint.listContactInfo().execute().toString();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(apples);

    JSONArray jsonArr = jObject.getJSONArray("items");

     for(int i =0 ; i<jsonArr.length() ;i++ ){
         JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nameFirst1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String nameLast1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String emailAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String streetAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String phone1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_PHONE);

                    //test to see if made it to string
                    Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "First Name: " + nameFirst1 + " Last Name: " + nameLast1);

                       address = coder.getFromLocationName(streetAddress1,5);

                        Address location1 = address.get(0);

                        // SET LAT LNG VALUES FOR MARKER POINT

                     lati = location1.getLatitude();
                         longi = location1.getLongitude();

                         Log.d("Location", "Location:" + lati + " " +  longi);

                         LocationData data = new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1);
                         locationList.add(data);
                         publishProgress(data);

     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
      return (long) 0;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(LocationData data) {
        // Add Marker on Map using data. This is called by
        // publishProgress(LocationData) on the UI Thread.
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
         .title(nameFirst1));

        Log.d("bananas", lati + longi + nameFirst1);
    }

    //WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO RETURN LocationData Class here
         // ADD MARKER TO MAP UI
    protected void onPostExecute() {

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class LocationData is defined inside an unreachable scope. Instead, define it in it's own .java file like so:

```
class LocationData {
    // final Fields
    // Constructor
    // Getters
}
```

or as a private static class of your outermost class if you don't use it anywhere else.

Then for your subclass of AsyncTask you could have something like:

```
private class AsyncJsonTask extends AsyncTask<Param, LocationData, Void>
{
    private List<LocationData> locationList = new ArrayList<LocationData>();
    // ...
    protected void doInBackground(Param) {
        // ...
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            // Do your stuff with JSon Objects
            // ...
            // Instanciate a new LocationData and pass it as progress:
            LocationData data = new LocationData(latitude, longitude, name);
            locationList.add(data);
            publishProgress(data);
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(LocationData data) {
        // Add Marker on Map using data. This is called by
        // publishProgress(LocationData) on the UI Thread.
        mMap.addMarker(/* marker */);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        // Assign outer class member field the value of the builded list
        // for future reference.
        mLocationList = locationList;
    }
}
```

This way, you can publish each marker individually on the map before fetching the next one.

As a side note, you should investigate the meaning of static methods and fields; your call to `LocationData.getLocationData()` would not be valid.

Comment: Thanks. I've placed the code as above. However I am not getting any map markers.

Comment: In the `onProgressUpdate()` you have to use the `data` argument to get your latitude and longitude such as `data.getLatitude()` to construct your Marker's Position. It defeats the purpuse of AsyncTask to access your Activity's variables directly from `doInBackgroud()` (i.e. when you do `lati = location1.getLatitude();`. Declare _local variables_ to hold your data instead.). Finally, as stated in the example, use a member List of your Activity to get a reference to you original data before the AsyncTask is GCed.

Answer (score 1):

onPostExecute runs in the UI thread. So any changes in the UX can be done here, in your case, adding markers to the map.

onPostExecute takes in the Result parameter returned from doInBackground().

You can learn more about AsyncTask from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

It got a nice example as well.

Comment: I can't seem to resolve my LocationData class reference within the onPostExecute.